# How to read and write EEPROM in ESP8266

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, eeprom

I need to know how I can write integer values in EEPROM and retain the value on power on.

```cpp
char *Red = strstr(myTestUrl, "/R");
if (Red) {
  int RedValue  = atoi(Red + 2);
  analogWrite(12, RedValue);
  Serial.println("Red :");
  Serial.println(RedValue);
}
```

I want to write `RedValue` in EEPROM. How can it be done?

Comment: Have a look in the EEPROM sample sketches that are installed when you add ESP8266 support to the arduino ide

Comment: having a question if there are any flash dependencies using the EEPROM. Can I flash with 1 MB (no SPIFFS) and have access to EEPROM? Thanks T

Answer (score 36):

While `EEPROM.read` and `EEPROM.write` are valid methods, it's like mopping the floor with a toothbrush. Use `EEPROM.put` and `EEPROM.get` instead.

For example:

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  uint addr = 0;

  // fake data
  struct { 
    uint val = 0;
    char str[20] = "";
  } data;

  // commit 512 bytes of ESP8266 flash (for "EEPROM" emulation)
  // this step actually loads the content (512 bytes) of flash into 
  // a 512-byte-array cache in RAM
  EEPROM.begin(512);

  // read bytes (i.e. sizeof(data) from "EEPROM"),
  // in reality, reads from byte-array cache
  // cast bytes into structure called data
  EEPROM.get(addr,data);
  Serial.println("Old values are: "+String(data.val)+","+String(data.str));

  // fiddle with the data "read" from EEPROM
  data.val += 5;
  if ( strcmp(data.str,"hello") == 0 )
      strncpy(data.str, "jerry",20);
  else 
      strncpy(data.str, "hello",20);

  // replace values in byte-array cache with modified data
  // no changes made to flash, all in local byte-array cache
  EEPROM.put(addr,data);

  // actually write the content of byte-array cache to
  // hardware flash.  flash write occurs if and only if one or more byte
  // in byte-array cache has been changed, but if so, ALL 512 bytes are 
  // written to flash
  EEPROM.commit();  

  // clear 'data' structure
  data.val = 0; 
  strncpy(data.str,"",20);

  // reload data for EEPROM, see the change
  //   OOPS, not actually reading flash, but reading byte-array cache (in RAM), 
  //   power cycle ESP8266 to really see the flash/"EEPROM" updated
  EEPROM.get(addr,data);
  Serial.println("New values are: "+String(data.val)+","+String(data.str));
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
}
```

**UPDATE**:  If you want to understand how the "EEPROM" is emulated in the ESP8266, you might want to reference https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/EEPROM, specifically, `EEPROM.h`.

Also, `EEPROM.end` is not needed, it simply clears the local byte-array cache of the flash/EEPROM from RAM.  It serves on other function.

Comment: you have saved my day, I was searching for more than five hours for a solution and you have gave it !

Comment: The actual Arduino documentation is really lacking here and the sources do not really help either. Is EEPROM.end() still needed? Why is begin(512) needed?
Plus a get()/put() combination or using update() would help to prevent EEPROM wear. Maybe you could update the answer.

Comment: I did a copy/paste of this exact code for a NodeMCU v3 and it's not retrieving the written value after a power cycle (I commented out the "write portion for the second run").

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit,  are you seeing ANY output in serial console?  are you sure baud rate is set correctly?   i don't have v3, just v0.9, so can't help if this is a forwards compatibility problem.

Comment: from reference "EEPROM.write does not write to flash immediately, instead you must call EEPROM.commit() whenever you wish to save changes to flash. EEPROM.end() will also commit, and will release the RAM copy of EEPROM contents."

Comment: What I have learnt practically is that EEPROM.commit() is absolutely necessary, at least on esp8266, in order for the EEPROM data to survive a reboot.

Answer (score 10):

`EEPROM.write(pos, val)` writes one byte (`val`) at the address giving by `pos`. An "int" in ESP8266 takes 4 bytes, so it's a little more complicated, because EEPROM works in bytes, not ints.

Here is a code for writing one int `val` at some position `pos` in the EEPROM:

```cpp
void eeWriteInt(int pos, int val) {
    byte* p = (byte*) &val;
    EEPROM.write(pos, *p);
    EEPROM.write(pos + 1, *(p + 1));
    EEPROM.write(pos + 2, *(p + 2));
    EEPROM.write(pos + 3, *(p + 3));
    EEPROM.commit();
}
```

and, of course, you need to read it back:

```cpp
int eeGetInt(int pos) {
  int val;
  byte* p = (byte*) &val;
  *p        = EEPROM.read(pos);
  *(p + 1)  = EEPROM.read(pos + 1);
  *(p + 2)  = EEPROM.read(pos + 2);
  *(p + 3)  = EEPROM.read(pos + 3);
  return val;
}
```

In Arduino you call `EEPROM.begin()`, but in ESP8266 you have to call `EEPROM.begin(n)`, where `n` is the total number of bytes you will need.

And remember that EEPROM have a short life span (by number of writes). You must minimize the number of writes!

EEPROM is permanent; you don't need to do nothing.

Comment: I did some searching and it seems EEPROMs can handle many more write cycles than flash storage but then flash storage also has a controller to stop using bad sections and keep working with the remaining working ones.

Comment: UPVOTED because of the life cycle alert.  100k cycles, some say.

Answer (score 2):

Method using the number of letters.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* SSID = "R360"; //MAX 32
const char* PASSWORD = "HFDYUK64323246"; //MAX 32

#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  EEPROM_ESP8266_GRABAR(SSID, 0); //Primero de 0 al 32, del 32 al 64, etc
  EEPROM_ESP8266_GRABAR(PASSWORD, 32); //SAVE

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(EEPROM_ESP8266_LEER(0, 32));//Primero de 0 al 32, del 32 al 64, etc
  Serial.println(EEPROM_ESP8266_LEER(32, 64));

  WiFi.begin(EEPROM_ESP8266_LEER(0,32).c_str(), EEPROM_ESP8266_LEER(32,64).c_str());

}
//
void loop() {}
//
void EEPROM_ESP8266_GRABAR(String buffer, int N) {
  EEPROM.begin(512); delay(10);
  for (int L = 0; L < 32; ++L) {
    EEPROM.write(N + L, buffer[L]);
  }
  EEPROM.commit();
}
//
String EEPROM_ESP8266_LEER(int min, int max) {
  EEPROM.begin(512); delay(10); String buffer;
  for (int L = min; L < max; ++L)
    if (isAlphaNumeric(EEPROM.read(L)))
      buffer += char(EEPROM.read(L));
  return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include <EEPROM.h>`

```
EEPROM.begin(size); //Size can be anywhere between 4 and 4096 bytes.
EEPROM.write(0, RedValue);   // To store in 0th Location
EEPROM.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 separate functions in my code on ESP8266 - one with `EEPROM.put()`, one with `EEPROM.get()`.

I had `EEPROM.begin(sizeof...);` only in `EEPROM.put()` function and `put` worked.
But it took me quite a while, until I found out, that it must be used before `EEPROM.get()` as well.